# Update mongodb document, if the document exists, else create

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a discord bot for me and my friends for tracking stats in CS GO 10 mans, and I am using cheerio for webscraping from the site that provides us the stats, and then pass them into mongodb. The **scraping** functionality works fine, but im trying to figure out how to avoid creating duplicate documents for each user. If I enter *userid 857575 it pulls the stats for that user, and puts in the DB, but if i call that multiple times, its making multiple documents in the DB. My question is, how would I get mongodb to update the document based on if the message author in discord matches the username in the db? So if username bob sends *userid3939 and bob already exists in the db, update the document. If bob doesnt exist, create document. code below, appreciate any tips.

```
    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    
 
    console.log(args);
    var userUrl = 'https://popflash.site/user/' +args;
    console.log(userUrl);
    console.log(message.member.user.tag);
 
     
     rp(userUrl)
         .then(function (html) {
             const arr = [];
             var i = 0;
 
             $('.stat-container', html).each(function (key, value) {
                 arr[i++] = $(this).find(".stat").text();
 
             });
         
             

             const stats = new Stats({
                 _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                 userName: message.member.user.tag,
                 userId: args,
                 HLTV: arr[0],
                 ADR: arr[1],
                 HS: arr[2],
                 W: arr[3],
                 L: arr[4],
                 T: arr[5],
                 win_percent: arr[6]
             });

            

             stats.save()
                 .then(function (result) {                   
                    let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setDescription(message.member.user + "'s 10 Man stats")
                        .setColor("#15f153")
                        .addField("stats", result)                        
                    
                         return message.channel.send(botembed);
                   
                    
                 })
                
         })
 
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "userid"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through [`db.collection.update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), you can specify the `upsert: true` option to get the behavior I think you're desiring. It will update an existing record if matched, otherwise it will create a new record.

Comment: What would that look like? the desired functionality would be if the username matches the discord username, the entire document would be updated